# undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 when trying to install OpenCV

Tags: macos, terminal, opencv3.0, osx-yosemite

im trying to install opencv in my mac. Ive searched for tutorials and they are all the same, so when i get to the part of running the command "make -j8" it executes just part of it because when it reaches 50% it shows me the error

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_qtkit.mm.o
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_videoio.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_ModPlug_GetCurrentOrder", referenced from:
  _modplug_read_packet in libavformat.a(libmodplug.o)
  "_ModPlug_GetCurrentPattern", referenced from:
  _modplug_read_packet in libavformat.a(libmodplug.o)
  "_ModPlug_GetCurrentRow", referenced from:
  _modplug_read_packet in libavformat.a(libmodplug.o)
  "_ModPlug_GetCurrentSpeed", referenced from:
  _modplug_read_packet in libavformat.a(libmodplug.o)
  "_ModPlug_GetCurrentTempo", referenced from:
  _modplug_read_packet in libavformat.a(libmodplug.o)
```

I dont know what is it and i have no idea how to correct it. I have Yosemite version 10.10.2 so i dont know if its an error of the OS.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the XCode commandline tools installed?

Comment: i dont, but is it because of that? all the tutorial ive followed use the terminal and the problem is when im executing the make command

Comment: you need the XCode commandline tools _because_ you are using the terminal. It includes compatible builds of gcc, make etc.  See [this technote from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2339/_index.html). If you have a recent XCode installed, the commandline tools should have been installed with it.

Comment: I have installed it but still i have the same error when the make command is at 50%